# Products are not deleting from backend

Tags: magento-1.9, products, admin-panel, delete

When we tried to delete products from backend, we got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_id ' in 'where clause'
```

We tried reindexing, still it didn't work for us.

[image]

Recently we didt installed extensions.

**Exception.log**

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', '')
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', '')
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(38509, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#11 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Comment: try delete from the database

Comment: @PradeepSanku but to do everytime from database is not possible for the situation we are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no field like **`product_id`** in catalog_product_entity table or any of eav tables which are related to products.

I suspect that there is some custom module working while you are trying to delete products.

Disable the custom modules one by one until you can identify which is causing the problem then you can consult them for further help, or provide more information about what your doing to help identify the problem.

**Edit:** As you told that after disabling all custom modules, still the problem is the same, therefore now please try to delete products programatically, like this:

```
<?php 
// Register a secure area
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
require_once './app/Mage.php';
Mage :: app("default") -> setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$productId = 1; //put your product id here
try{   
    Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load( $productId )->delete(); 
    echo "deleted successfully";exit;
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();exit;
} 
?>
```

**Update:** If you are able to delete from custom code, then you have either core module modifications or some custom code (it may be some observer) is creating problem. You need to recheck by disabling all custom modules at once. If still problem persists, then you can take backup of core adminhtml catalog module and upload it from fresh copy of magento with same version.

Comment: please check `catalog_product_entity` table in question, i am trying disabling modules.

Comment: You can see that there is no **product_id**
 field in this table.

Comment: okay, now i am trying disabling custom modules.

Comment: i checked by disabling all modules in backend , except `Mage_core` modules, but still it didt worked.

Comment: as this not problem with any modules, now what to do ?

Comment: Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks , but please help me to delete products through backend. because  client is going to delete whichever products he want, its going to be difficult for him as he dont have much knowledge about about these things.

Comment: Please see update.

Answer (score 2):

`entity_id` is the appropriate column name. `product_id` column does not exist.

Comment: so is we need to create `product_id` column ?

Comment: no. simply change product_id to entity_id in your query. don't modify the database, especially if you are not 100% sure what you are doing.

Comment: can you please give me sql query that i can run in phpmyadmin

Comment: please give me the query you are running, I can fix it for you

Comment: no, i have no idea about it.

Comment: how are you selecting the products you want to delete? or do you just want to delete them all?

Really, you should be using php and Magento's native functionality to delete the products instead of running the delete query directly against the database. You can easily corrupt your database the way you want to do it.

Comment: we are using backend to delete products, now we dont want to delete products through phpmyadmin. we want to delete products through backend only.

Comment: That doesn't make sense then. You shouldn't need any queries at all to delete through backend only. I am trying to help but its becoming less clear what you need and I don't want to give you advice thats going to screw up your database.

Comment: okay, than how to solve this error : `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_id ' in 'where clause'` i want to delete products from backend only.  because client is going to delete whichever products he want, its going to be difficult for him as he dont have much knowledge about about these things

Comment: What action are you taking to reach that error? Are you attempting to use the product grid located at Catalog > Manage Products? If so, are you selecting checkboxes and then choosing the delete option?

Comment: you are right...

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? It almost sounds like someone messed with some code and didn't know what they were doing.

Comment: 1.9 . but we tried disabling all modules , recently one of our devoloper added some Api related code for mobile app. they are not here now.

Comment: I am sorry, it's really difficult to say without seeing the codebase. I think someone changed something and forgot to put it back. I really think that's the problem. I work in 1.9 all the time and have never encountered this issue.

Comment: is our database table i posted in question is fine ?

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly as it should. I am pretty sure the problem is within your code somewhere. Do you know if the previous developer used GIT or some sort of version control? That may help you track down the root of the problem.

Comment: sorry, we  are not using git or svn.

Comment: you may want to start using git in the future so if you or some developer makes a mistake, you can see exactly what has changed and revert to a previous state if necessary. sorry buddy, i just don't have enough information to figure it out

Comment: I posted exceptional.log in question, can you look at once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43173/discussion-between-shawn-abramson-and-baby-in-magento).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to delete the product using some custom code, you should try to replace `product_id` with `entity_id` if you are trying to delete products from the `catalog_product_entity` table.

Comment: please check `catalog_product_entity` table in question. even for `Default` attribute set products also i can not able to delete.